# Extract select option value from object HTMLSelectElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to extract values from select options from two different fields in the same form, convert the values into strings and combine the two strings to form a URL slug.

```
<select onChange="functionOne(this);">
   <option value="test1">Test One</option>
   <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
</select>

<select onChange="functionTwo(this);">
   <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
   <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
</select>

<button id="submit" class="btn" type="button" onclick="submit();">Submit</button>


function functionOne(e1) {
  var slug1 = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value;
}

function functionTwo(e2) {
  var slug2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;
}

function submit(){
  window.location = 'https://example.com/' + slug1 + '-' + slug2);
  
}
```

That's my code, simplified for the purpose of this example.

The problem is I get the following result:

[https://example.com/[object](https://example.com/%5Bobject) HTMLSelectElement]-[object HTMLSelectElement]

How do I get string values from select options that I can use as slugs in a URL? If anyone has a better way of doing this, I'm willing to accept suggestions.

Comment: I doubt you get that, because `slug1` and `slug2` only accessible inside `functionOne` and `functionTwo` - when simplifying code it's important that you don't change the way the code actually works ... your submit would end up with `https://example.com/undefined-undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your `slug1` and `slug2` to be accessible as global `var` scope to be able to use them in `submit` function.

Also, you could also get a `return` from `functionOne` and `functionTwo` in your `submit` function.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var slug1
var slug2

//Change function
function functionOne(e1) {
  slug1 = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value;
}

function functionTwo(e2) {
  slug2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;
}

//Submit
function submit() {
  //window.location = 'https://example.com/' + slug1 + '-' + slug2);
  let location = 'https://example.com/' + slug1 + '-' + slug2;
  console.log(location) //https://example.com/test1-test1
}
```

```html
<select onChange="functionOne(this);">
  <option disbaled selected>Choose</option>
  <option value="test1">Test One</option>
  <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
</select>

<select onChange="functionTwo(this);">
  <option disbaled selected>Choose</option>
  <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
</select>

<button id="submit" class="btn" type="button" onclick="submit();">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare variables outside in order to use them.

```js
var slug1 = "";
var slug2 = "";

function functionOne(e1) {
  slug1 = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value;
}

function functionTwo(e2) {
  slug2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;
}

function submit() {
  console.log(slug1);
  console.log(slug2);
  //window.location = 'https://example.com/' + slug1 + '-' + slug2;
}
```

```html
<select onChange="functionOne(this);">
  <option value="test1">Test One</option>
  <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
</select>

<select onChange="functionTwo(this);">
  <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
</select>

<button id="submit" class="btn" type="button" onclick="submit();">Submit</button>
```

And since you ask for better way suggestion, you can use just one function on submit, not much better, maybe just cleaner.

Example:

```js
function submit() {
  var slug = [];
  // create array
  [...document.querySelectorAll("select")].forEach(sel => {
    slug.push(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value);
    // get values of each select and push into array
  });
  var link = 'https://example.com/' + slug[0] + '-' + slug[1]
  // use array
  
  //window.location = link
  console.log(link);
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="test1">Test One</option>
  <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
</select>

<button id="submit" class="btn" type="button" onclick="submit();">Submit</button>
```